# Is it a good idea to use a worker role to connect to a database to retrieve data?

Tags: azure

New to Windows Azure was not sure if its a good idea to use a worker roll to connect to a database and retrieve data? And populate a datagrid? Or stick with a data source control?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of worker roles as background services running on your computer i.e. applications with no UI. While your worker role can certainly fetch the data from the database but since there's no UI, you would not be able to bind that data anywhere. You would need to make use of a web role and have a data grid there and bind the data to that grid. So the approach would be to have web role fetch the data from the database and bind it to a grid on one of the aspx page in your webrole.